# Transform txt data to List separated by empty lines

Tags: c#

I need some help trying to transform txt files in easy searchable data in c#.

My txt files are something like this:

```
Field1: Data
Field2: Data
UselessField1: Data
UselessField2: Data
UselessField3: Data
Field3: Data
Field3: Data
Field3: Data
Field4: Data
Field4: Data
Field4: Data

Field1: Data
Field2: Data
UselessField1: Data
UselessField2: Data
UselessField3: Data
Field3: Data
Field4: Data
Field4: Data
Field4: Data
Field4: Data
```

Fields3 and Field4 can have n lines and would be good to separate to other lists like Field1 with Fields3 and Field1 with Fields4 so I can link it later.

I also want to skip the Useless fields.

Maybe this is something simple but I'm complicating it too much, I would appreciate if someone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i'd create a class with a meaningful name and meaningful properties:

```
public class MeaningfulClassName
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

Now you can use LINQ to filter all for only the relevant lines in the file and split the key and the value by `:`. But if you want a safe and clean approach you need reflection and a dictionary to map the text-file fields with the properties in the class. For example:

```
var myClassType = typeof(MeaningfulClassName);
var allowedProperties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>
{
    { "Field1", myClassType.GetProperty("Property1") },
    { "Field2", myClassType.GetProperty("Property2") },
    { "Field3", myClassType.GetProperty("Property3") },
    { "Field4", myClassType.GetProperty("Property4") }
};
```

The LINQ query to select only the relevant tokens which also skips your useless fields:

```
var dataLines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => l.Split(':').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray())
    .Where(arr => arr.Length == 2 && allowedProperties.ContainsKey(arr[0]));
```

Following loop reads the data and adds the instances of the class to a list:

```
var myList = new List<MeaningfulClassName>();
MeaningfulClassName currentObject = null;
foreach (string[] token in dataLines)
{
    string fieldName = token[0];
    string fieldValue = token[1];
    PropertyInfo pi = allowedProperties[fieldName];
    // first field specifies the beginning of the next object
    if (fieldName == "Field1")
    {
        if (currentObject != null)
            myList.Add(currentObject);
        currentObject = new MeaningfulClassName();
    }
    pi.SetValue(currentObject, fieldValue);
}
if (currentObject != null)
    myList.Add(currentObject);
```

now you have all objects and can search them easily, for example with LINQ

Comment: I had to separate the lists making more 2 classes but was a great start :)
Thanks you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This code will turn your data into a list of dictionaries, and dictionaries will have field names as keys and list of data as value.

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
        List<Dictionary<string,List<string>>> alldata = new List<Dictionary<string,List<string>>>();
        String[] lines = r.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },StringSplitOptions.None);
        alldata.Add(new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            if (item == "") { alldata.Add(new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()); continue; }
            var lst = alldata[alldata.Count - 1];
            string key = item.Split(':')[0];
            if (key.StartsWith("Useless")) continue;
            if (lst.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                lst[key].Add(item.Split(' ')[1]);
            }
            else {
                lst[key] = new List<string>();
                lst[key].Add(item.Split(' ')[1]);
            }
        }
```